# Testing a google map application with interactive polyline on Selenium

Tags: google-maps, gwt, selenium

I am using Selenium to test my app based on google maps. I am performing `clickAt` operations in selenium to draw a polyline but it isn't working. It gets all the point at one single position. Please help..

My current testcase looks as follows:

```
<tr>
  <td>open</td> <td>URL</td> <td></td>
</tr><tr>
  <td>contextMenuAt</td> <td>id=googleMap</td> <td></td>
</tr><tr>
  <td>click</td> <td>id=gwt-uid-1</td> <td></td>
</tr><tr>
  <td>clickAt</td> <td>//div[@id='googleMap']/(snip)/img[4]</td> <td>100,400</td>
</tr><tr>
  <td>clickAt</td> <td>//div[@id='googleMap']/(snip)/img[4]</td> <td>100,200</td>
</tr><tr>
  <td>clickAt</td> <td>//div[@id='googleMap']/(snip)/img[4]</td> <td>0,0</td>
</tr><tr>
  <td>clickAt</td> <td>//div[@id='googleMap']/(snip)/img[4]</td> <td>0,0</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: You could perhaps post your current code?

Comment: <tr>
 <td>open</td>
 <td>URL</td>
 <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>contextMenuAt</td>
 <td>id=googleMap</td>
 <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>click</td>
 <td>id=gwt-uid-1</td>
 <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>clickAt</td>
 <td>//div[@id='googleMap']/div/div/div[2]/div/img[4]</td>
 <td>100,400</td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>clickAt</td>
 <td>//div[@id='googleMap']/div/div/div[2]/div/img[4]</td>
 <td>100,200</td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>clickAt</td>
 <td>//div[@id='googleMap']/div/div/div[2]/div/img[4]</td>
 <td>0,0</td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>clickAt</td>
 <td>//div[@id='googleMap']/div/div/div[2]/div/img[4]</td>
 <td>0,0</td>
</tr>

Comment: If the graph creation is "drag and drop", you could try `mouseDownAt`, `mouseMoveAt` and `mouseUpAt`. Does that give better results?

Comment: Nope its not a drag and drop. It is a click operation wherever i click the node should get added. And to end the polyline i should either click on the first or last node. And i even tried out mouseDownAt and mouseUpAt but even that didn't work